# Finding closed form of $ S(n)= \sum_{i=0}^n a^{q^i} $

Tags: summation

I'm trying to find a closed form of $ S(n)= \sum_{i=0}^n a^{q^i}  $ for positive constant params $a, q, n$. I searched it in google but I couldn't find any. I searched it in [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Sum%22,%20%22sumfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22x%5E(a%5Ek)%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Sum%22,%20%22sumvariable%22%7D%20-%3E%22k%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Sum%22,%20%22sumlowerlimit%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Sum%22,%20%22sumupperlimit2%22%7D%20-%3E%22n%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,%20%22sum%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D), but I didn't get any result.I thought there is some set like geometric progression but no results in google.

I tried finding more fundamental properties for the set $a_1,a_2...,a_n$ as $a_{k+1} = a_k^q$, but with not much of a success.

The one thing I managed to find is the sum $A(n) = \sum_{i=0}^n log(a^{q^i})$ which was trivial but still couldn't get any results with this sum in [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22Sum%22,+%22sumfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22log(x,x%5E(a%5Ek))%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22Sum%22,+%22sumvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22k%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22Sum%22,+%22sumlowerlimit%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22Sum%22,+%22sumupperlimit2%22%7D+-%3E%22n%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,+%22sum%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D) for some reason...

So my question is : Is it possible to find closed form of $S(n)$ and if so what method should I use to find it?

**EDIT:**

A theory of mine: If there is closed form function: $f(\sum_{i=0}^n x_i^q) = \sum_{i=0}^n x_i^{q^2} $
then $S(n+1) = f(S(n))+a$ however there might be set $Y$ where:
$S(n) =\sum_{i=0}^n y_i^{q^n}$ then   $S(n+1) = f(S(n)) + a$ is different from the old $S(n+1)$. So in order for $f(x)$ to exist $X$ must be a set of $a_1,a_2...,a_n$ elements and as such $f(x)$ can't be closed form and $S(n)$ respectively.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Take a look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about formatting your question with MathJax to make it more readable

Comment: @DMcMor I tried it but for some reason $\sum_{i=0}^n a^(q^i) $ didn't look good, so I thought it would be more clear using plain text. If you have any Ideas about the mathjax I should use please write it to me so I can fix my question's appearance

Comment: @user2377766 Try a^{q^i} instead it formats like this $a^{q^i}$

Comment: I guess you might add some conditions like $a>0$ etc

Comment: @MANMAID changed them all to positive

Comment: Try multiplying $S(n)$ by $a^q$ and then rewrite what you get in terms of S(n). You should get something like $a^q S(n) = S(n) + x - y$ then solve for S(n). This is how you do it for the regular geometric series

Comment: @FullofDill thats the first thing I tried but since $a^q*a^{q^k}= a^{q^k+q}$ it didn't quite work for me in that direction...

Comment: oi, total brain fart. sorry

Comment: @FullofDill Hahah. I get confused too. Not used to that level of powers ... :D

Comment: It's $\Delta S(n)=a+(a^q-1) S(n)$ with $\Delta S(n):=S(n+1)-S(n)$ . You can search how such problems are handled in the literature of *Concrete Mathematics* . Perhaps you will find out that there is no closed form or that it's necessary to use Analysis (see: *Euler-Maclaurin formula*) .

Comment: @ user90369 will do